# How to process variable input JSON with Golang Gin

Tags: go

I trying to write my first app on Gin with Golang
There is some service that post some variable JSON to controller
Input data like this:

```
{
  "shipping:{
    "address_id1": {..some data..},
    "address_id2": {..some data..}
  },
  "items": {
    "item_id1": {..some data..},
    "item_id2": {..some data..}
  }
}
```

So, I don't know items keys and I need to process through items array
How can I do it with Gin?
In PHP I will walk through associative array like

```
foreach ($_POST['shipping'] as $key => $value) {
  ..some logic with data..
}
```

In other words, how to work with input posted data correctly?

Comment: Use a `map` when the keys of a JSON object are unknown. Then you can range over the map just like you do in PHP, e.g. `for key, value := range v.Shipping { ... some logic with data... }` (here `v` would be the instance of a struct into which you unmarshaled the incoming JSON, the struct would have two fields (`Shipping`, `Items`) each of type `map[string]any`).

Answer (score 2):

In Go-Gin we can use **Bind()** or **BindJSON()** of Gin's context object to access the data which is posted as JSON.

You can use a nested map when the keys are unknown.

```
type Shipping map[string]map[string]string
type Items map[string]map[string]string

type RequestPayload struct {
    Shipping Shipping `json:"shipping"`
    Items    Items    `json:"items"`
}

// controller
func ShippingController(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var request RequestPayload
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&request); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for key, value := range request.Items {
        fmt.Println("The key : ", key)
        fmt.Println("The value : ", value)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subject: Simplifying MongoDB Array of Objects Update in Go with Gin

Hi there,

I recently faced a challenging task of updating an array of objects in my MongoDB document using Go with Gin. The document structure looked like this:

```json
{
  "permissions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "users",
      "list": []
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "customers",
      "list": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Finding a solution was a bit of a headache, and I tried several approaches. Eventually, I found a clean and effective solution. Here's how I did it:

#### Document Structure:

```golang
type PermissionsList struct {
    PermissionList []Permission `json:"permissionList" bson:"permissionList"`
}

type Permission struct {
    ID   interface{} `json:"id" bson:"id"` 
    Name string      `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    List []string    `json:"list" bson:"list"`
}
```

#### Decode JSON and Insert:

```golang
var permissions = new(models.PermissionsList)
decodeErr := utils.DecodeJSON(context, permissions)
if decodeErr != nil {
    return decodeErr, "Failed to decode body", nil, 500
}
```

#### JSON Decoder Function:

```golang
func DecodeJSON(context *gin.Context, modelInterface interface{}) error {
    err := context.BindJSON(&modelInterface)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

#### Update MongoDB Document:

```golang
idErr, objectId := utils.ToObjectId(id)
if idErr != != nil {
    return idErr, "Invalid user id", nil, 422
}

opts := options.FindOneAndUpdate().SetUpsert(true)
filter := bson.D{{"_id", objectId}}
update := bson.D{
    {
        "$set",
        bson.D{
            {"permissions", permissions.PermissionList},
        },
    },
}
```

This structure worked seamlessly for updating the MongoDB array of objects. Feel free to use it in your projects or adapt it to fit your specific needs.